# Oracle - Cannot set inmemory_size?

Tags: oracle, parameters, columnstore

I am having problem with changing the parameter INMEMORY_SIZE in oracle database. I used the below script to set this parameter:

`ALTER SYSTEM SET inmemory_size=300M scope=spfile;`

And it raised the error:

> **ORA-02096:** specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option

> *Cause:   Though the initialization parameter is modifiable, it cannot be modified using the specified command.

The default value is 0, and I checked that it is modifiable:

> Name | ISSYS_MODIFIABLE |

> inmemory_size |  IMMEDIATE    |

Is there anyone had similar error or can help me with that?

I am using oracle23c.

Comment: No idea, that's for DBAs (we're mostly developers here) so maybe you could try on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle. Though, there's no Oracle **23c** (at least, not yet), the last version is 21c.

Comment: Are you trying to set this parameter in a pluggable DB when its value is 0 in the CDB? That would cause this error. [Find out more](https://orastory.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/oracle-12c-multitenant-inmemory-pre-basics/)

Comment: @APC thank you, I solved it. I forgot to enable it in CDB first